# Is there a way to automatically load insecure content in Chrome browser for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Similar to this question but for the mobile space...
https://superuser.com/questions/487748/how-to-allow-chrome-browser-to-load-insecure-content

Is there a way to automatically load insecure content in Chrome browser for Android?

I understand that ideally it should be fixed at the web site level but I don't have that ability.

Comment: I've been all through the settings and there's nothing about insecure content. I don't know if other browsers might handle it the way you like.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103646/run-google-chrome-with-flags-not-from-chrome-flags) might help to force apply that flag manually. Might not work, but not hurt to try.