# Run Google Chrome with flags (not from chrome://flags)

Tags: chrome-for-android, chromium

There are command line flags (or "switches") that Chromium (and Chrome) accept in order to enable particular features or modify otherwise default functionality.

- [Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
- [Run Chromium with flags](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)

I want to add `--sync-url` flag to use my sync server instead of Google sync servers. `chrome://flags` only enable/disable flags but won't let you add a new flag.

Tried Chrome 41.0.xx and Chromium 43.0.xxx shell with:

```
# echo "chrome <flags>" > /data/local/tmp/android-webview-command-line
# echo "chrome <flags>" > /data/local/tmp/content-shell-command-line
# echo "chrome --sync-url whatever" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line
```

Any idea how to run Chrome with flags on Android or directly add these to the default profile?

Comment: Hey, if my answer has helped you, I'd appreciate it if you could "accept" it. This community only works if people who volunteer answers get something back :)

Comment: No luck, not reflected in chrome://sync-internals or chrome://version

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the entire command into the `/data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line` file. For example, I usually you want to skip the "First run experience", and I do:

`# echo "chrome --disable-fre" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line`

You probably need

`# echo "chrome --sync-url whatever" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line`

Comment: Seems the OP has updated his question without informing you that it's not working.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yep.. I am pretty sure this is the correct way to set a command line switch in mobile chrome as I use it regularly. There must be some other reason the sync url is not being set. In any case, I think I answered the question asked.

Comment: Reading from other source, I found similar syntax for Chromium (different file, as already mentioned by OP), so I believe this answer should be correct. Perhaps the problem is the sync URL itself.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through this myself on Android 5.0.1. It's [what was mentioned by Munim](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/104165/44325) with two important tweaks.

1. In `chrome://flags`, enable the "Enable command line on non-rooted devices" flag, this makes Chrome look in `/data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line` (instead of `/data/local/chrome-command-line`)
2. Create the `chrome-command-line` file with `chrome` plus the additional flags you want (no need to repeat existing flags found in `about:version`), e.g. `chrome --sync-url whatever`
3. Change the mode of the `chrome-command-line` file to `755`, e.g. `chmod 755 chrome-command-line`
4. Restart Chrome and verify that the flags you specified appear in `about:version` at the beginning