# How to Bypass Certificate Errors in Google Chrome Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, https

Apparently desktop Chrome has a flag called `--ignore-certificate-errors` that allows you to bypass all certificate warnings. Is there an equivalent for Android Chrome? I checked in `chrome://flags` but nothing there.

Comment: Perhaps try [this approach if possible](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103646/run-google-chrome-with-flags-not-from-chrome-flags) first. Doesn't mean that it can work, but doesn't hurt to try either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a permanent bypass, but the flag

> chrome://flags/#remember-cert-error-decisions

should make it less painful.

Comment: This flag is no longer available. I'm not able to find out when it was removed, but I've used it for a while and just realized that it is no longer there.

Comment: Yep it's gone. What a bummer!

Answer (score 0):

On modern Chrome versions you need to disable follow flag:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-recurrent-interstitial
```

Comment: Like the accepted solution, this too seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have chrome connected to a remote chrome debugging session (see here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging), you can inspect the tab on the remote side, click on the miniature displayed screen on the remote side and type "thisisunsafe" just like in normal chrome.