# Use flags in Chrome command line without root

Tags: chrome-for-android, chromium

I'm using Chrome version 74.0.3729.136. My phone is not rooted. I'm trying to use flags in Chrome command line without root.

I use the guide from [Run Chromium with flags](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags). According to that guide, with flags, it can be done.

The guide said:

> For production build on a non-rooted device, you need to enable "Enable command line on non-rooted devices" in chrome://flags, then set command-line in /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line. When doing that, mind that the first command-line item should be a "_" (underscore) followed by the ones you actually need. Finally, manually restart Chrome ...

I successfully set up the flag "Enable command line on non-rooted devices". But then I need to copy the data file to `/data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line` - and I cannot do that.

I tried:

1. Command like that:

   ```
   C*:\WINDOWS\system32>adb shell 'echo --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=TestTest > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line'*
   The system cannot find the path specified.
   ```
2. Recommendation from [Run Google Chrome with flags (not from chrome://flags)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103646/run-google-chrome-with-flags-not-from-chrome-flags)

   ```
   # echo "chrome --sync-url whatever" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line
   ```
3. Use different Android OS (5-7).
4. Use construction like the following for copying files:

   ```
   run-as com.example.app "cat /sdcard/temp_prefs.xml > shared_prefs/com.example.app_preferences.xml"
   ```

but nothing happened.

Anyone has tried it?

Answer (score 1):

It worked. You need to set the flag and next, from the command line:

```
adb shell

shell@:/ $ echo "chrome --user-agent=MyUser" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line
```

To confirm it, you can download the file from the phone

```
adb pull /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line C:\
```