# Pass flags to Chromium

Tags: chromium

I've built Chromium from source for arm64.  I was reading [this page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags/) which discusses how to pass flags to Chromium upon startup.  It gives the following example:

```
out/Default/bin/content_shell_apk argv --args='--foo --bar'
```

My `out/Default/bin` doesn't contain a `content_shell_apk` but rather a `chrome_public_apk`.  The rest of this question is based on the (possibly mistaken) assumption that those two are the same.

That script accesses other files in my Chromium source directory meaning that I need to copy some if not all of the files to the Android.  That's a non-trivial ask given how big the source is.  Furthermore, the script invokes `python3` which doesn't exist on my Android.

All of this brings me to my situation.  I don't know how to use that script to start Chromium so I've instead been doing

```
am start org.chromium.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

However, adding flags to that invocation doesn't appear to have any effect.

How do I either

1. Run the `chrome_public_apk` script on the Android or
2. Launch the installed APK with flags

?

Comment: Possible dupes? [Run Google Chrome with flags (not from chrome://flags)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/103646/44325), [Use flags in Chrome command line without root](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/212679/44325)